# Ajax call duplicated each time

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page with a form. The form is dinamically loaded with jquery.load in document.ready loop.

```
$('#storico').load('bp/storico.php?az=<?php echo $id; ?>');
```

I have then created a delegated event to handle form submission:

```
$(document).on('click','#update',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var att_stor = $('#attivo_storico').val();
var pass_stor = $('#passivo_storico').val();
var az = <?php echo $id; ?>;
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "bp/storico1.php",
        data: {attivo_storico: att_stor, passivo_storico: pass_stor, azione: az},
        success: function(data){
    data1=data.split("|");
    if(data1[0].trim() == "Successo"){ 
        $("#storico").empty().html('<center><p class="success">'+data1[1]+'</p></center>').animate({opacity:1}, 'slow');
    }else if(data1[0].trim() == "Errore"){
        $("#storico").empty().html('<center><p class="err">'+data1[1]+'</p></center>').animate({opacity:1}, 'slow');    
    }
    },
        complete: setTimeout(function(){$('.container').load('bp/businessplan.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>');},3000)
    });
});
```

The ajax call works like a charm and do the following:

1. submit the form and update db (no issues);
2. update the div containing the form with a confirmation message (no issue)
3. reload the container div to update the whole page with the new data (used elsewhere in the page)

The first loop works flawlessy. The second time the call is executed twice, the third is four times, then eight times. If i load something else in container and then go back to this page the execution starts again from one. 
This issue doesn't affect how the scripts work but I'd like to understand why it duplicates the calls (as Firebug shows me)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you call `$(document).on(...` multiple times?

Comment: It sounds like you're triggering document.ready multiple times and reassigning the click handler again. Put a console.log in there so you can tell if that's happening or not.

Comment: Can you add your html code? When you are setting html inside elements the load callback will be called again. [http://api.jquery.com/load/](http://api.jquery.com/load/) "If a "complete" callback is provided, it is executed after post-processing and HTML insertion has been performed."

Comment: No, I don't call document.on multiple times, neither the document.ready.
My only guess is that when I reload the container div (that includes the form div) the previous jquery code is cached and not discarded. The html structure of the whole page is always left unchanged and never reloaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using:

```
$(document).off().on('click','#update',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var att_stor = $('#attivo_storico').val();
var pass_stor = $('#passivo_storico').val();
var az = <?php echo $id; ?>;
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "bp/storico1.php",
        data: {attivo_storico: att_stor, passivo_storico: pass_stor, azione: az},
        success: function(data){
    data1=data.split("|");
    if(data1[0].trim() == "Successo"){ 
        $("#storico").empty().html('<center><p class="success">'+data1[1]+'</p></center>').animate({opacity:1}, 'slow');
    }else if(data1[0].trim() == "Errore"){
        $("#storico").empty().html('<center><p class="err">'+data1[1]+'</p></center>').animate({opacity:1}, 'slow');    
    }
    },
        complete: setTimeout(function(){$('.container').load('bp/businessplan.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>');},3000)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).off('click','#update'); // off old click events
$(document).on('click','#update',function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var att_stor = $('#attivo_storico').val();
var pass_stor = $('#passivo_storico').val();
var az = <?php echo $id; ?>;
if(request && request.readystate != 4){
    request.abort();  // for abort last one
}
request = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "bp/storico1.php",
        data: {attivo_storico: att_stor, passivo_storico: pass_stor, azione: az},
        success: function(data){
    data1=data.split("|");
    if(data1[0].trim() == "Successo"){ 
        $("#storico").empty().html('<center><p class="success">'+data1[1]+'</p></center>').animate({opacity:1}, 'slow');
    }else if(data1[0].trim() == "Errore"){
        $("#storico").empty().html('<center><p class="err">'+data1[1]+'</p></center>').animate({opacity:1}, 'slow');    
    }
    },
        complete: setTimeout(function(){$('.container').load('bp/businessplan.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>');},3000)
    });
});
```